# Is it possible to propagate a type parameter of a type parameter to a parameterized class in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, typeclass

Assume I have a trait `Foo[A, B]`.

I want to define a class `Bar`, parametrized with `Foo` and reuse `Foo` type parameters in `Bar` methods. Something like shown below (this snippet doesn't compile):

```
trait Bar[Foo[A, B]] {
  def doSmth[C](A => C): C
}
```

Is there any way to achieve something similar and still have just a single type parameter in `Bar` declaration?

p.s. it would also be great if someone can suggest the right terminology for the described stuff.

Comment: If `Foo` is a trait, what is the purpose of including it within the type arguments? What is the use case?

Comment: @m-z: I'm trying to make a computation chain based on `Bar` (I'm not sure if it can be called a `Monad` though). `Foo[A, B]` represents current computation step, it can be smth like `Function1`. I'd really like the `Bar` part to carry some computation context in its type.

Comment: Would you need to know about `Foo` within `Bar`? Or only the type parameters? That is, if you did have multiple type parameters, would it be `Bar[A, B]` or `Foo[A, B, F[A, B]`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but maybe this is somewhere near where you want to go.

```
trait Foo[A,B]
trait Bar[A] { self: Foo[A,_] =>
  def doSmth[C](atoc: A => C): C
}
```

Or, using a type alias.

```
trait Foo[A,B] {type FooA = A}
trait Bar { self: Foo[_,_] =>
  def doSmth[C](atoc: FooA => C): C
}
```

This means that a `Foo` is required when you have a `Bar` in the mix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the # operator to access type members of class or traits.

```
trait M {
    type A
    type B
  }

  class F[X,Y] extends M {
    type A = X 
    type B = Y 
  }

  trait Bar[F] {
    def doSmth[C](x: M#A => M#B): C
  }
```